# Is there any way to disable DASH playback in the HTML5 player?

Tags: google-chrome, video, youtube, html5

I like watching YouTube videos using the HTML5 player rather than the Flash player because I can get 60 FPS video. However since I have poor internet, I would like to be able to pause the video and wait for it to buffer fully. This requires me to disable DASH playback. I have been unable to find a tool or extension to do this while remaining with the HTML5 player. Is this possible? I'm using Google Chrome.

Comment: Hi! Are you sure the HTML5 player is using DASH? I've found references that claim that switching to HTML5 is actually a way to avoid it.

Comment: @Alpha Positive. The video will buffer a certain amount an then stop. It will not buffer further under any circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

There now are extensions around that disable DASH playback (notably the [YouTube Center](https://github.com/YePpHa/YouTubeCenter/wiki/Features) extension), but note that disabling DASH also disables all resolutions except 360p and 720p30.